# Rebbe Akiva's Name

Tags: sources-mekorot, names, acronyms, rabbi-akiva-ben-yosef

I heard from someone that the name עקיבא stands for "**י**ש **ק**ונה **ע**ולמו **ב**שעה **א**חת."

1) Why is that?

2) What's the source for it?

Comment: Are you sure they weren't referring to the name יקעבא?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> יש קונה עולמו בשעה אחת על ידי מסירות נפש
>   באמת נתעלה ונהפוך כל הרע שבו לטוב גמור והוא ר״ת עקיבא
>   יש קונה עולמו בשעה אחת והיינו במסירות נפש נתעלה
>   למעלה למעלה

from http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_20632_507.pdf (Heichal Habracha by the Komarna Rebbe)